# Don't understand error message [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using PHP with sqlsrv drivers and am trying to run this query:

```
$InsertProfileQry = "INSERT INTO [ProfileRecord]
                (rec_no,
                dos_date,
                profile_status,
                age,
                age_group,
                dob,
                gender,
                last_name,
                middle_name,
                first_name,
                address,
                address2,
                city,
                full_city,
                state,
                zip,
                phone,
                status,
                collection_date,
                lrn_vs_private,
                hospitalized,
                submitted_by,
                date_time
                )
                VALUES ($rec_no,
               $dos_date,
               $profile_status,
               $age,
               $age_group,
               $dob,
               $gender,
               $last_name, 
               $middle_name,
               $first_name,
               $address,
               $address2,
               $city,
               $full_city,
               $state,
               $zip,
               $phone,
               $status,
               $collection_date,
               $lrn_vs_private,
               $hospitalized,
               $submitted_by,
               getdate() )";
```

Here's sample data that I entered (I use print_r to view my data before inserting it, checking for errors):

```
Array
(
    [dos_date] => 2022-04-30
    [profile_status] => Active
    [first_name] => John
    [middle_name] => 
    [last_name] => Doe
    [dob] => 1965-01-01
    [age] => 57
    [age_group] => 50s
    [gender] => M
    [address] => 123 Maple Street
    [address2] => 
    [city] => MyCity
    [state] => TX
    [zip] => 78545
    [phone] => 999-888-9999
    [status] => Active
    [collection_date] => 2022-04-29
    [lrn_vs_private] => Public
    [hospitalized] => N
    [submitted_by] => Jane Doe
    [submit_new] => SUBMIT
)
```

And I get the error message:

```
[0] => 42000
            [SQLSTATE] => 42000
            [1] => 102
            [code] => 102
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 's'.
```

So, I have check everywhere were there is an 's',  but I don't see anything that would cause this error.

Comment: If you parametrise your statement, instead of using a highly insecure injection method, this issue disappears.

Comment: Likely the strings need to be quoted. Would be best off parameterizing query.

Comment: `[age_group] => 50s` - strings should be quoted, or use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) and parameter binding.

Comment: How do you execute the statement (which driver do you use)? It's a simple task to define and execute parameterized statement, usually using PDO.

Comment: I was missing the quotes, but I will use prepared statements. Thanks for everyone's help.